# Convert from char to byte

Tags: c++

Hello is there a way that makes you convert from char to byte.
I know that in c# there is the Method.

```
Convert.ToByte('a');
```

But what is it in c++? I have tryed google it but i cant find any answer.

Comment: What's different between a `char` and a byte?

Comment: The `char` type is the smallest addressable unit in C++, it is always a "byte".

Comment: So, if you want a byte, what do you mean? 8 bits? A `char` is not guaranteed to be 8 bits, but it normally is. There are other datatypes that can guarantee 8 bits.

Comment: @Muscampester With the caveat that there must be a built in type of that size in order for them to exist.

Comment: There is no `byte` data type in C++

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, I was thinking `std::bitset<8>` for example. It is true that even `uint8_t` is optional.

Comment: @Muscampester Ha.  Hadn't thought about using that when you really need to be sure.  Not sure how fun i would be to work with though.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, not much fun, and probably not that fast either. Perhaps for maximum portability it would make sense work with `uint_fast8_t` which is guaranteed to exist, but reading and writing to files needs extra work. Maybe most practical would be to assume that `char` is 8 bits and then add an assert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike C#, C++ does not have a built-in data type named `byte`. In addition, its `char` type has a size of one byte, as opposed to C#, which uses 16-bit characters, so the conversion is always trivial.

If you want your code to be explicit about the sign of your eight-bit data type, use [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) header, declare a variable of type `uint8_t`, and assign the character to it:

```
uint8_t x = 'a';
```

Comment: It is also possible to use `unsigned char`  (although, admittedly, `char` types are not required to be exactly 8 bits).

Comment: Note that it's bad form to set a uint8_t to a character literal. char * should be used for strings, char for ascii characters or fragments of UTF-8 characters, uint8_t for bytes (small integers or streams of data which are not yet decoded),

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean That's true. However, this is what OP's code in C# becomes when translated to C++.

Comment: I used unsigned char and it worked :) thanks for all the help